# como obtener la ultima parte de una url en Js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Me llegan en un arreglo varias url de las que quiero extraer la ultima parte

http://130.10.1:8087/pruebas/downloadFile/archivo.txt

hasta ahora solo he logrado obtener lo que va antes del nombre del archivo, pero lo que quiero es solo sacar el nombre de dichos archivos archivo.txt

```
var url = "http://130.10.1:8087/pruebas/downloadFile/archivo.txt";

var ultimaPosicion = url.lastIndexOf('/');
var nivelAnterior = url.substr(0, ultimaPosicion);
console.log(nivelAnterior);
```

Soy nuevo en Js, me podrian ayudar por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el método .split() puedes hacer que una string se guarde en un arreglo, dividiendolo según el char que le mandes como parámetro, si mandas un '/' como parámetro te va a dividir el string usando / como referencia, hacemos un split al string, y tomamos el último valor del arreglo, lo que nos va a retornar el valor que buscas

```js
var url = "http://130.10.1:8087/pruebas/downloadFile/archivo.txt";
const arr = url.split('/')
console.log(arr[arr.length-1]) // retorna archivo.txt
```

Comment: versiones recientes de `js` también permiten `console.log(arr.at(-1))` para imprimir el último elemento.

Comment: no sabía que se podía hacer eso con los arreglos, gracias por la info

Comment: Mas sencillo y mas corto es: `url.split("/").pop()`

Answer (score 0):

Esto tambíen te puede funcionar seguramente:

```js
var url = "http://130.10.1:8087/pruebas/downloadFile/archivo.txt";
console.log(url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1))
```

donde lo que hacemos es, mediante el método [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) extraemos el trozo de cadena que empieza en la posición conseguida con [lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) hasta el final, y le sumamos +1 para evitar la barra `/`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar `split("/")` para separar la cadena en cada `/` que encuentre. Luego de esto deberías ir a la última posición del arreglo de la siguiente forma:

```
ultimaPosicion[ultimaPosicion.length - 1]
```

Tu código sería así:

```js
var url = "http://130.10.1:8087/pruebas/downloadFile/archivo.txt";

var ultimaPosicion = url.split("/");
var nivelAnterior = ultimaPosicion[ultimaPosicion.length - 1];
console.log(nivelAnterior)
```